# Mono LLVM and LLVM-IR

Tags: c#, mono, llvm

I am playing with Mono LLVM (http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime:Documentation:LLVM) and it seems like they are using LLVM here as a JIT, not really as a code generator. But according to the docs, they go through LLVM-IR before generating native code :

1. first, normal mono JIT IR is generated from the IL code
2. the IR is transformed to SSA form
3. the IR is converted to the LLVM IR
4. the LLVM IR is compiled by LLVM into native code

So, I am wondering if there any way to catch this 3rd phase and use the IR to feed my LLVM backend. That would allow me to get C# to LLVM-IR front end for free.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does 'IR' mean in this context? Also a minor nit: JITting could probably be considered a form of code generation (asm is code afterall).

Comment: IR means 'intermediate representation', LLVM's assembly language

Answer (score 5):

Mono's LLVM support works by attempting to load `libmono-llvm.so` from the appropriate `$libdir`, e.g. on OSX `/usr/bin/mono` will load `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Libraries/libmono-llvm.dylib`. See the LLVM loading code in [mono/mini/mini-llvm.h](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/mini/mini-llvm.h), specifically [mono_llvm_load()](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/mini/mini-llvm.h#L86) and [try_llvm_load()](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/mini/mini-llvm.h#L68).

So it looks like if you name your LLVM backend `mono-llvm`, it will be used when you launch mono as `mono --llvm`. That said, `mono_llvm_load()` appears to require particular exports from the `mono-llvm` library, such as `mono_llvm_init` and `mono_llvm_cleanup`, so I'm sure that some additional work will be needed to your LLVM backend in order to allow Mono to use it, and I'm not sure where to find this out (other than `grep`ping for "LLVM" in Mono's sources...).

This also means that the LLVM backend may not be reusable from a prebuilt mono; that is, you may need to build your own mono in order to use your LLVM backend, as a prebuild mono will be providing a `mono-llvm` backend that may not be pluggable. (I have no idea how pluggable or not pluggable the LLVM backend is.)